# Transaction does not work. Hyperledger Composer

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I try to submit transaction via REST API server, it returns 500 error.
I started to receive this error after update to 0.19.7 Hyperledger Composer version.

BNA with that transaction and model has been tested in Hyperledger Composer playground and there it works good.

Here is error from response I get

```
{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: Generated invalid JSON: ...
at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:980:34)\n    at <anonymous>"}}
```

Here is log from rest server

```
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: Generated invalid JSON: ...
at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:980:34)
at <anonymous>
```

---

Here is transaction on submitting which I get error:

```
/**
 * @param 
{com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.transaction.ResponseConfiguration} responseConfiguration
 * @transaction
 */
function responseConfiguration(responseConfiguration) {
    var subOrder = responseConfiguration.subOrder;
    subOrder.productionTime = responseConfiguration.productionTime;
    return updateSubOrder(subOrder, 'approvedConfig');
}

function updateSubOrder(subOrder, state) {
    var order = subOrder.order;
    subOrder.state = state;
    return updateAssetInRegistry(subOrder).then(function () {
        return updateOrderIfSubOrdersStateEquals(order, state, subOrder);
    }).then(function (order) {
        return updateAssetInRegistry(order);
    });
}

function updateAssetInRegistry(asset) {
    return getAssetRegistry(asset.getFullyQualifiedType())
        .then(function updTheReg(registry) {
            return registry.update(asset);
        });
}

function updateOrderIfSubOrdersStateEquals(order, state, modifiableSubOrder) {
    var shouldBeUpdated = 0;
    return Promise.all(order.subOrders.map(function (subOrder) {
        return getAssetFromRegistry(subOrder)
            .then(function (subOrder) {
                if (state === subOrder.state || modifiableSubOrder.getIdentifier() === subOrder.getIdentifier()) {
                    shouldBeUpdated++;
                }
                return subOrder;
            });
    })).then(function () {
        if (shouldBeUpdated === order.subOrders.length) {
            order.state = state;
        }
        return order;
    });
}
```

Model:

contract_transactions.cto

```
namespace com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.transaction

import com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.SubOrder
import com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.Order

transaction ResponseConfiguration {
    --> SubOrder subOrder
    o Integer productionTime
}
```

contract.cto

```
namespace com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract

import com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.asset.definition.AssetDetails
import com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.asset.entity.SimpleAsset
import com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.partner.PrivateOwner

enum OrderState {
    o createdConfig
    o approvedConfig
    o acceptedByClient
    o rejectedByClient
    o manufacturing
    o readyForDeliver
    o delivering
    o delivered
}

asset SubOrder identified by subOrderId {
    o String subOrderId
    --> AssetDetails assetDetails
    --> Order order
    o String note optional
    o Integer productionTime optional 
    --> SimpleAsset orderedAsset optional
    o String clientSign optional
    o OrderState state
    --> Invoice invoice optional 
}

asset Order identified by orderId {
    o String orderId
    --> PrivateOwner client
    --> SubOrder[] subOrders
    o OrderState state
    --> PrivateOwner courier
}

asset Invoice identified by invoiceId {
  o String invoiceId
}
```

partners.cto

```
namespace com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.partner

abstract participant Person identified by email {
    o String email
}

enum Role {
    o Client
    o Seller
    o Courier
}

participant PrivateOwner extends Person {
    o Role businessRole
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is the exact transaction JSON you submitted through the  REST API transaction class API `/POST` ?

Comment: `{
  "$class": "com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.transaction.ResponseConfiguration",
  "productionTime": "0",
  "subOrder": "com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.SubOrder#-707019134"
}
`

Comment: i've updated to 0.19.8 and error did not appeared.

Comment: ok cool. In 0.19.8 there was a fix for JSON serialization, (circular refs and oncepts in particular) so not sure if this affected you then.  I didn't see the transaction model but your JSON would likely be `{ "$class": "com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.transaction.ResponseConfiguration", "productionTime": "0", "subOrder": "resource:com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.SubOrder#-707019134" } ` ie `resource:` - see examples in Step Six of this tutorial [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the transaction model,  but your valid JSON would likely be

```
{ 
"$class": "com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.transaction.ResponseConfiguration", 
"productionTime": "0", 
"subOrder": "resource:com.iba.linux.chainnetwork.contract.SubOrder#-707019134" 
}
```

ie `resource:` prefix - see some examples in Step Six of this tutorial - specifically how a relationship identifier is specified in the JSON construct [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries)